# Decrypting reviewId from Google Business API

Tags: c#, encryption, google-api, google-reviews

I am consuming `accounts.locations.reviews.list` from [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list) to get a list of all the reviews of each location.

The `Review` [object](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#Review) that is returned contains a `reviewId` field, which according to the documentation is "encrypted unique identifier", and a few other fields.

Now when google sends a "new review" via email, there is a link to respond to that review in the form `https://business.google.com/n/{locationId}/reviews/{someReviewId}`

For example:

`https://business.google.com/n/12345678901234567890/reviews/ChdDShUAMG9nS0VJQ0FnSUQyNS1UZGlnRRAB`

I need to construct the response URL for each review.

`reviewId` is 76 chars.

`someReviewId` is 36 chars.

I was able to match `reviewId` and `someReviewId` by the content of the review, but I cannot find a the encryption method used by google so that I can get `someReviewId` by decrypting `reviewId`.

Is it even possible?

An actual `reviewId` `someReviewId` pair:

```
AbFvOqkIVAD_XerdvMYkiM9lC8xe8o4WHBcKTFk_aOzgryalloKaj64UJcWPVZ9poOerhnfpHpwr
ChdDSUhNMG9nS0VJQ0FnSUNlOElEVHFBRRAB
```

Comment: Same, bump. Have you had any success?

Comment: aftraid not. I should probably go to google forums and ask there. Not much hope though

Comment: I have contacted support and the API does not provide this.They also don't provide encryption method.